# what I need to do call dev environment api from my VS 2022 for testing

Tags: dns, webapi

I have a WebApi, it was deployed onto dev, UAT and production with the same domain name.

- DEV : [https://myapp.com/GetProduct=>](https://myapp.com/GetProduct=%3E) it will point server to ip 11.221.124.12
- UAT : [https://myapp.com/GetProduct=>](https://myapp.com/GetProduct=%3E) it will point server to ip 11.221.124.13
- PROD: [https://myapp.com/GetProduct=>](https://myapp.com/GetProduct=%3E) it will point server to ip 11.221.124.14

Now from my client I want to call the Dev web Api for testing purpose. So I modified my host file like below:

> 11.221.124.12 myapp.com

Now if I call https://myapp.com/GetProduct from postman I am getting data from dev server. At the same time if I call this API from VS 2022 Its hitting production server.

What is the mistake i made here. What do I need to do to call the dev api from VS 2022?

Comment: Why host them on the same domain name? That just seems like it's begging for trouble. Create a separate entry for each environment.

Comment: We can't change the host name . My question is while calling from postman its pointing dev server as per host file setting. Why its not working from VS 2022

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that a request ends up at a certain IP address you can override the destination address of the httpclient for different environments in your appsettings.json.

So for instance for `production` you would have the `appsettings.json` config section

> "serviceBaseAddress": "https://myapp.com"`.

For your local `development` you would overwrite that appsetting in your `appsettings.Development.json` to point to the exact server ip you want to reach

> `"serviceBaseAddress": "https://11.221.124.12"`.

It would ofcourse also be preferential to not use exactly the same base url for all environments. Since you cannot change the domain perhaps you could setup the different web APIs to utilize different base path. Resulting in something like:

```
DEV   : https://myapp.com/DEV/GetProduct  => ip: 11.221.124.12
UAT   : https://myapp.com/UAT/GetProduct  => ip: 11.221.124.13
PROD  : https://myapp.com/GetProduct      => ip: 11.221.124.14
```